# Difficulty of the Mathematics GRE Exam

Tags: gre

I've been gathering information about the GRE mathematics subject test. Going over most of the tets available at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922417/gre-subject-test-in-mathematics-where-can-i-find-related-past-papers-solution?noredirect=1&lq=1), I see that to get a scaled score of, say, 800+, one now need a higher raw score on the newer tests compared to the older tests. This naturally led me to infer that perhaps the exams of recent years have become easier, making the curve shift toward the right of the range. However, the following [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861741/how-difficult-is-gre-math-compares-to-these-two-past-exams?rq=1) mentions that the subject tests have actually become harder! I was hoping if someone could expound on this issue. If the subject tests have become harder, why does one need to a larger raw score to get the same scaled score.

Comment: Define "harder"?  If the questions are about the same, but you have to get a higher raw score to achieve the same scaled score, then in some sense the exam has become harder.

Comment: (At least in mathematics), by this year the general types of questions asked are very well known, and many people study intensely and specifically toward this exam (rather than studying mathematics itself...) Drill in timed-test-taking helps in obvious technical ways. So the raw scores go up. But/and at some point (in grad admissions for our program) I stopped caring about timed, multiple-choice appraisals, so this inflation does not disturb me at all.